# Using a control to update a null value

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create a control (bound to a field in a table) that when you click it, the value updates.   All is fine with my code when the value is not null however i need the control (named 'ObjectivesMetrics') to offer the user to update the value even when the underlying field value is null so that the value passes from null to the value "metrics not identified".   My code below works fine up until the last two rows. The error message i get is Run Time 424 - Object Necessary

```
Private Sub Comando107_Click()

    If ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics identified") Then
        ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics agreed")
    ElseIf ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics agreed") Then
        ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics partially agreed")
    ElseIf ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics partially agreed") Then
        ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics not agreed")

    ElseIf ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics not agreed") Then
        ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics complete")
    ElseIf ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics complete") Then
        ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics not yet identified")
    ElseIf ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics not yet identified") Then
        ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics identified")

    ElseIf ObjectivesMetrics Is Null Then
        ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics not yet identified")


End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test for the null first.

```
Private Sub Comando107_Click()

    If IsNull(ObjectivesMetrics) Then
        ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics not yet identified")
    ElseIf ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics identified") Then
        ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics agreed")
    ElseIf ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics agreed") Then
        ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics partially agreed")
    ElseIf ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics partially agreed") Then
        ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics not agreed")

    ElseIf ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics not agreed") Then
        ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics complete")
    ElseIf ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics complete") Then
        ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics not yet identified")
    Else
        ObjectivesMetrics = ("metrics identified")
    End If

End If
```